# Open source harness design tool

Tags: open-source, electronics

I am trying to look at a software that can help me draw wiring and harnesses. Many forums recommend using Visio, paint brush and such.

But I want too use a software that has features like Bom generation as well. The bom shall include wire colour, twisting, length etc.

I tried using rapid harness tool. It is perfect but the free version has serious limitations. Can anyone recommend any open source tool please?

Comment: I you need it for work, I would suggest purchasing the tool you find perfect (the standard version doesn't seem too expensive as a long-term investment..) . I remember trying to find a similar tool several years ago, but without much success.

Comment: Have you looked at www.aucotec.com they have a product called Harness Design and Manufacturing.

Comment: @Eugene - I just had a look, that Rapid Harness pricing is a monthly price, when billed annually. So, it's actually QUITE expensive. If you use it regularly, it may be worth it, but if you don't use it every day, it's probably more than most can afford.

Answer (score 3):

A new challenger has appeared!

[WireViz](https://github.com/formatc1702/WireViz)

[image: Sample output]

Answer (score 2):

Pickering has a web-based tool for wire harness design. It's not open source, but it's free: https://cables.pickeringtest.com/

It can generate a PDF with the drawing, BOM, pinout tables, etc.